# ng.probe(selector) always results in NULL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

So I know of an application for which I wanted to create a bookmarklet, I got to know that application is built using Angular 6. I did a bit of googling and found a way to modify DOM using this [article](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/)

the first step is to call `probe` method on `ng` with `selectors`, I tried varies selectors such as document.body, app-root, $0, etc, however result is always same as NULL.

I am not sure what's missing here.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The `ng.probe()` method will only work if the application is not running in production mode.

Comment: any alternative way to debug ?